# Git - How to checkout without modifying files?

Tags: git

How to checkout without modifying files?

Is there a git command that can do the following things?

```
~/target-dir (some-branch)$ mkdir /tmp/tmp-target-dir
~/target-dir (some-branch)$ cp -r * /tmp/tmp-taregt-dir
~/target-dir (some-branch)$ git checkout -f master
~/target-dir (master)$ cp -r /tmp/tmp-target-dir/* .
```

Comment: You can stash, check out, and then pop the stash

Comment: I'll have to resolve conflict if I use stash.

Comment: Yes, but you can always pick your version as the correct version when resolving conflicts

Comment: No, what I wanna perform is the exact result like above. I will then use git diff to see the overwritten result.

Comment: The result will be misleading, as you'll be replacing files you haven't even touched. For example, if master modified file A, but you didn't, A would show up with the inverse of the change master made if you were to run your above code. Why not just run `git diff master`?

Comment: Is your goal to only create new files that exist in master?  Or is your goal to "be on" master with none of its changes, taking its tree?

Answer (score 4):

Use reset (--soft Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all but resets the head to <commit>):

`git reset --soft master`

It resets your current branch (if it is not master) not touching the files.

But seems more close to what you are asking is to move head to another branch, while keeping everything as is, just simply:

`git symbolic-ref HEAD refs/heads/master`

Answer (score 1):

> I'll have to resolve conflict if I use stash

Then another approach is:

- to [create a second working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309) with [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) (git 2.5+, preferably git 2.8+):

  ```
  cd /targetdir
  git worktree add ../master master
  ```
- to add the files from some-branch working tree to the master working tree

  ```
  cd ../master
  git --work-tree=../targetdir add -A .
  ```

That way, you can do a `git diff` and see what was added/modified/removed by importing `some-branch` working tree into `master`  working tree.

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the code you wrote, you want to copy all the things from `some-branch` to `master`, so in fact you want to merge `some-branch` into `master`

```
~/target-dir (master)$ git merge --no-ff some-branch
```

This `--no-ff` flag make you sure that you will have the merge commit and you will be able to git diff it clearly.

If during the merge you face conflicts - you'll just need to handle them